# Add Row number to a new column

Tags: sql, sybase, rownum

I want to create a new column and populate the value of each row in that column with the row number.

This could be achieved in oracle by doing this.

```
alter table mytable add (myfield integer);
update mytable set myfield = rownum;
```

How would this be done in SYBASE ASE?

Comment: I don't know about the exact Sybase syntax to do a UPDATE FROM, but `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)` creates the result same as `rownum`, you just need to sort the rows (maybe Sybase supports a dummy like `ORDER BY 1`)

Answer (score 6):

```
alter table mytable 
add id bigint identity not null
```

That's all. There will be a column `id` in every row that contains a unique sequence number for that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
create column table some_names
     (ID bigint not null primary key generated by default as IDENTITY,
      NAME nvarchar(30));
```

And now we can do things like this:

```
insert into some_names (name) values ('Huey');
insert into some_names (name) values ('Dewey');      
insert into some_names (name) values ('Louie');
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case when I tried to do it with **identity** column time it wasn't able to finish in  reasonable time (196400 rows).

Fast and easy way was to create an INT column and fill it up using a temporary variable **@id** incremented after each row.
This solution finished in ~4 seconds.

```
alter mytable add myfield INT

DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE mytable
SET @id = myfield = @id + 1
```

You can find more info here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1467/populate-a-sql-server-column-with-a-sequential-number-not-using-an-identity/

Comment: This did not work. Many of my columns ended up with ID = 1. In a table with 2 million rows, the id never got above 43000 because of the repeats